Can't vectorize this function - works with constants but returns ValueError operands could not be broadcast together
I wrote a python function I would expect to allow vectorization, using np.where and np.maximum. However, when attempting to call that function by passing dataframe columns, I get the error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together ..."
The function works fine when passing constants. I'm stuck on how to rewrite it to allow vectorization, ie accept pd.Series as arguments. I want to calculate the mean payoff for each row of the pandas.DataFrame, ie, an array of (2,1)
Update 2: Updated code slightly to fix a few issues
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
times, dt = np.linspace(0, 1, 251, retstep=True)
B = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), size=(100, 250)).T
S = np.exp((0 - .15 ** 2/ 2) * dt + .15 * B)
S = 4.5 * S.cumprod(axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'days': [230,250], 'otype': ['c','p'], 'strike': [4.8,4.3], 'ko': [None, 'do'], 'b': [5,4.55]})

def montecarlo_payouts(montecarlo, j, opt, k, kotype = None, b = 0, i=1):
    #adjust daycount for index starting at 0
    i = i - 1
    j = j - 1
    #deal wih argument types
    opt = opt.str.lower() if isinstance(opt, pd.Series) else opt.lower()
    k = k.to_numpy() if isinstance(k, pd.Series) else k
    k = k[:,None] if isinstance(k, (pd.Series, np.ndarray)) else k

    #vanilla option payoffs for call and put
    conditions = [np.logical_or(opt == 'c',opt == 'call')]
    payoff = np.where(conditions, np.maximum(montecarlo[j] - k, 0), np.maximum(k - montecarlo[j], 0))
    return payoff.mean(axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'days': [230,250], 'otype': ['c','p'], 'strike': [4.8,4.3]})
payout = montecarlo_payouts(S, 250, df['otype'], 5)


Please include all your imports.

What is x?  Shape, dtype?

Does the error tell you the problem shapes?

@hpaulj I went ahead and updated to code to include the calculation of S (the array that feeds the function. When the code errors from using df['otype'] the broadcast error shapes are (2,) (2,100) and (2,100)

@jared imports added

What don't you understand?  Those shapes? where, or broadcasting?

@hpaulj The issue is I'm getting an error when I perform string comparisons. When I pass a pandas column of strings and attempt to compare in np.where or np.select I get errors. I can pass pandas columns of floats without issue and the code performs as expected

The otype=='c' condition is clearly (2,) (given how its called),   But the np.maximum(montecarlo[j] - k, 0), and the montecarlo[j] (S) argument inside it, is producing this 2d array, (2,100).  Globally S.shape is (250,100).

@hpaulj the logic i'm going for is: for each row in the pd.DataFrame, if it is has otype of 'c', then perform the first array calculation, else perform the other calculation (reversed)

The condition array needs to be (n,1) shaped to broadcast with (n,100) arrays.

I was able to get it working using suggestions from @jared on another post and properly handling my series arguments.
Working code:
def montecarlo_payouts(montecarlo, j, opt, k, kotype = None, b = 0, i=1):
    #adjust daycount for index starting at 0
    j = j - 1
    #deal wih argument types
    j = j.to_numpy() if isinstance(j, pd.Series) else j
    opt = opt.str.lower().to_numpy() if isinstance(opt, pd.Series) else opt.lower()
    kotype = kotype.str.lower().to_numpy() if isinstance(kotype, pd.Series) else kotype.lower()
    k = k.to_numpy() if isinstance(k, pd.Series) else k
    k = k[:,None] if isinstance(k, np.ndarray) else k
    b = b.to_numpy() if isinstance(b, pd.Series) else b
    b = b[:,None] if isinstance(b, np.ndarray) else b
    kotype = kotype[:,None] if isinstance(kotype, np.ndarray) else kotype

    #vanilla option payoffs for call and put
    itm = montecarlo[j] - k
    conditions = [np.logical_or(opt == 'c',opt == 'call')]
    callorput = np.where(conditions, 1, -1)
    payoffs = np.maximum(itm * callorput.transpose(), 0)
    return payoffs

